# Как в воспользоваться OutputDebugString?

Tags: c, ассемблер

У меня есть инструкция чтения регистра eax в int переменную:

```
register int ip asm("%eax");
```

Как можно сделать эту инструкцию валидной для использования в Visual Studio?
Я понимаю,что %eax - это просто eax регистр. Я изменил на такое:

```
register int ip;
__asm mov ip, eax;
```

Верна ли моя интерпретация?

Как тогда воспользоваться функцией нахождения дебаггера?

```
void IsDebugString()
{
    register int ip;
    __asm
    {
        mov ip, ecx;
    }
    printf("\n%d IP is \n", ip);
    OutputDebugString("Banter");
    if (ip>1)
    {
        printf("Debugger detected - OutputDebugString");
        return;
    }
}
```

Как узнать, что возвращает система на нахождение дебаггера?
Подумал об альтернативном варианте:

```
OutputDebugString("Banter");
    if (GetLastError() == 0)
    {
        puts("DEGUUG");
    }
    else
        puts("nope");
```

Запускаю на проверку в Release .exe, в командной строке разработчика Visual Studio.Он всё равно считает, что это дебаг

Comment: В приведенном вами коде вы получаете значение регистра `ecx` в текущий момент в переменной `ip`, но какое отношение значение этого регистра имеет к отладчику?... Вы явно хотите что-то не то, о чем пишете.

Comment: @Harry, можете посмотреть изменения?

Comment: Вам не это нужно? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent

Answer (score 1):

Не ответ, но в комментарий не влезу...

Все, что вы делаете - это просто копируете в стековую переменную `ip` (стековую, слово `registrer` не работает, да и никогда не гарантировало размещения в регистре) **текущее** значение регистра `ecx`:

```
?IsDebugString@@YAXXZ PROC              ; IsDebugString, COMDAT

; 9    : {

    push    ecx

; 10   :     register int ip;
; 11   :     __asm
; 12   :     {
; 13   :         mov ip, ecx;

    mov DWORD PTR _ip$[esp+4], ecx

; 14   :     }
; 15   :     printf("\n%d IP is \n", ip);

    push    DWORD PTR _ip$[esp+4]
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_0M@POIKFFKO@?6?$CFd?5IP?5is?5?6@
    call    _printf
    add esp, 8
```

Как видите - все честно :) - `mov   DWORD PTR _ip$[esp+4], ecx`

У меня ощущение, что вы хотите некий *алиас* регистра `ecx`, но это совсем другой вопрос, насколько я понимаю, в рамках VC++ не решаемый.

P.S. А вот, кажется, ответ... XY-проблема налицо :)

Вы хотите выяснить, работаете под отладчиком или нет? для этого воспользуйтесь функцией [`IsDebuggerPresent()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent).

Comment: я ищу ему альтернативу, но не NTstatus.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы верно записали в переменную `ip` значение из `eax`. Если в ip мусор, а в eax какие-то все же есть, я бы вынес ассемблерную вставку в отдельную функцию.

```
 int ip = 0;
 // вне main
 void func (int ip){
 _asm {

   mov DWORD PTR ip, ECX
  }
 }
```

Comment: однако в ip всё равно мусор

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что этот мусор - не то, что содержится в `eax`?

Comment: @Harry, тогда я немного дополню вопрос